# How to remove BRO IDS (installed from source using make) from Ubuntu-16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, bro

I installed BRO 2.5.3 from `source code` using `make` in ubuntu-16.04. 
However I can't uninstall it using

```
make uninstall
```

Any ideas how to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

That's not a typical Make task.  To remove Bro, assuming you have used the configure script with no options:

```
 rm -rf /usr/local/bro
```

Answer (score -1):

**Just to remove Bro Packages**

> sudo apt-get remove bro

and if you want to remove all the dependent packages also then:

> sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove bro

Later you can find the location of the nsm folder and delete it with sudo permissions.

Comment: You can only `apt-get remove` what you installed with `apt-get install`. The question specifically says they installed from source.

Comment: @Mohammed, @octobus I would suggest installing [link]https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall even if you have already run `make install`, you can still use `CheckInstall`. Normally, `CheckInstall` will overwrite everything that `make install` created. After that just use `dpkg -r <package.deb>`, and everything should be removed.